# installing wso2 api manager on google cloud standalone server

Tags: server, wso2, virtual-machine, gcloud

have created a  centOS virtual machine instance on google cloud, but need to deploy wso2 api manager over it. In official page of wso2, i need to download the api first then run some commands to install it. but in gcloud, downloading api is not possible. Is there anything i need to do in order to install api manager on gcloud?

Comment: You can download the zip file to local machine and scp it to your gcloud instance.

Comment: @AnuruddhaLankaLiyanarachchi could you plz , share a link of transferring files from local machine to gcloud via scp? i hv worked with winscp, but dont know how to transfer the files to gcloud via winscp.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp